# SQL Like function Broken? or Limited?

Tags: sql, sql-like, wonderware

I am trying to use the `LIKE` function to get data with similar names. Everything *looks* fine but the data I get in return is missing some values when I get back more than ~20 rows of data.

I have a very basic query. I just want data that starts with Lab, ideally for the whole day, or at least 12 hours. The code below misses some data and I cannot discern a pattern for what it picks to skip.

```
SELECT History.TagName, DateTime, Value  FROM History 
WHERE History.TagName like ('Lab%') 
AND Quality = 0
AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Full' 
AND DateTime >= '20150811 6:00'
AND DateTime <= '20150811 18:00'
```

To give you an idea of the data I am pulling, I have Lab.Raw.NTU, Lab.Raw.Alk, Lab.Sett.NTU, etc. Most of the data should have values at 6am/pm, 10am/pm, and 2am/pm. Some have more, few have less, not important. When I change the query to be more specific (i.e. only 1 hour window or LIKE "Lab.Raw.NTU") I get all of my data. Currently, this will spit out data for all tags and I get both 6am data and 6pm data, but certain values will be missing such as Lab.Raw.NTU at 6pm. There seem to be other data that is missing if I change the window for the previous day or the night shift, so I don't think it has to be with the data itself. Something weird is going on with the LIKE function but I have no idea what.
Is there another way to get the tagnames that I want besides like? Such as Tagname > Lab and Tagname <= Labz? (that gives me an error, so I am thinking not)

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is missing data or is it just returning results in a different order from what you expect?  Perhaps your interface is limiting the number of rows being returned.

Comment: If you want to include records with a time of, say, 18:00:30 in the 6 a.m. - 6 p.m. data then you will need to use `AND DateTime < '20150811 18:01`.

Comment: Are you running that script from SQL Management Studio or are you checking the results from your end application?

Comment: Yes, my data is at exactly 6pm but my original query was from midnight to midnight and I still had the issue. I get the same results in SQL Management Studio. I do feel that it might have something to do with the rows being returned, but a 24 hour query returns 200 rows, just with some items missing. 
I will say that this is a proprietary Historical database that I did not make. Is it possible they have messed with something to skew the results?

Comment: Can you give a few more detailed examples? Like show us a query that returns everything, then show us the expanded query that excludes certain rows. Unless you have a syntax error I can't see why this issue would occur.

Comment: What I want:

`SELECT History.TagName, DateTime, Value  FROM History 
WHERE History.TagName like ('Lab%') 
AND Quality = 0
AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Full' 
AND DateTime >= '20150811 0:00'
AND DateTime <= '20150811 23:59'`

What gets my all data:
`SELECT History.TagName, DateTime, Value  FROM History 
WHERE History.TagName like ('Lab.Raw.N%') 
AND Quality = 0
AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Full' 
AND DateTime >= '20150811 0:00'
AND DateTime <= '20150811 23:59'`

Comment: Or even this get all `SELECT History.TagName, DateTime, Value  FROM History 
WHERE History.TagName like ('Lab%') 
AND Quality = 0
AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Full' 
AND DateTime >= '20150811 17:00'
AND DateTime <= '20150811 18:00'`

Comment: You are not querying a normal SQL table. You are querying a view for a extension table that fetches data from virtual tables in the Historian, which fetches data from history blocks (files) stored on the server.

Comment: You could try explicitly providing the TagNames instead of using the LIKE clause. The LIKE clause is supported, but there could be anomalies in the retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the `Like` operator correctly; that could be a red herring.  Check the data type of the `DateTime` field.  If it is character based such as varchar you are doing string comparisons instead of date comparisons, which could cause unexpected results.  Try doing an explicit cast to ensure they are compared as dates:

```
DateTime >= convert(datetime, '20150811 6:00')
```